# Collection View Cell Will Not Change Size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to create an application with a collection view. No matter what I do, I cannot change its size. In the view controller, it looks [larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7nAN.png) than when program is [ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWMi9.png) (photos below). The image view is the same size as the cell. I have also tried using

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
         return CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: screenWidth/3)
    }
```

But nothing changes.

Here is the viewcontroller code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let array = ["1,", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
        cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")

        return cell
    }

}
```

myCell is just a UICollectionViewCell class with an outlet to the imageview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the sizeForItemAt method, make sure that your class adopts both **UICollectionViewDelegate** and **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** protocols.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this function in your viewController

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {        
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, height: <Desired Height>)
    }
}
```